# How to ignore particular USB device given a vid and pid?

Tags: macos, usb, kernel

I'm running Sierra v10.12.5. I'm trying to flash an stm32f100 chip using openocd. As per the [documentation](http://openocd.org/doc/html/Debug-Adapter-Hardware.html):

> For info the original ST-LINK enumerates using the mass storage usb class; however, its implementation is completely broken. The result is this causes issues under Linux. The simplest solution is to get Linux to ignore the ST-LINK using one of the following methods:
>
> - modprobe -r usb-storage && modprobe usb-storage quirks=483:3744:i
> - add "options usb-storage quirks=483:3744:i" to /etc/modprobe.conf

I tested this solution on an Ubuntu machine and it works. Now I'd like to replicate this on a Mac but I can't seem to find any information on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

`modprobe` does not exist in macOS / OS X as it is a Linux-specific program.

The macOS equivalent is `kextload`.

Have you tried to use [pystlink](https://github.com/pavelrevak/pystlink) to flash your chip?